# JWT: Verify Signature Secret Format.

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, jwt, express-jwt

I am trying to create a JWT.  I am following the format provided here: https://jwt.io/

Under VERIFY SIGNATURE there is a property called `secret`

```
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  secret    
)
```

How do I create that secret in code?  Can it be any string or it has to be a certain format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret can be anything: when it is a string you can paste it verbatim in the "secret" entry, when it is a binary secret (a sequence of bytes) you should first base64-encode it, paste it in the "secret" box and tick the "secret base64 encoded" button.

Note that jwt.io can verify an existing JWT against a provided key, it cannot generate JWTs and sign them.